Running a function in a background thread in Swift IOS
I am a beginner to swift and ios development and need some help with structured concurrency. I need a long running function to execute on a background thread, and be cancelled if it is called again before completing. Unfortunately, my code allows the 2nd call to start before the currently running task finishes cancelling.
Can someone provide an example of how to do this properly?
I removed the "guts" from my code and just left the concurrency structure in place.
The function "doLongWork()" is called from the UI, and it runs the function "longWork()" in the background after cancelling the previous task if one exists.
class SomeClass {
    var workItem: DispatchWorkItem?
    var queue1 = DispatchQueue(label: “serialQueue”))

    func doLongWork() {
        if workItem != nil {
            queue1.async(flags: .barrier) { /* barrier */ }
            workItem?.cancel() 
        }
        workItem = DispatchWorkItem { self.longWork() }
        queue1.async{ self.workItem?.perform() }
    }

    func longWork() {

        func recursiveFunction() {
            if let cancelled = workItem?.isCancelled {
                if cancelled { return }
            }
            // calculations
        }

        recursiveFunction()
        
        if let cancelled = workItem?.isCancelled {
            if cancelled {return}
        }

        OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
            // update ui
        }
        workItem = nil
    }
}


First, your code isn't using Swift concurrency.  It is using a Grand Central Dispatch DispatchQueue.
You have a few issues with your code.
The first is that you are explicitly calling perform on your work item.  You don't need to do this.  You can simply submit the DispatchWorkItem to the DispatchQueue and it will be executed.
The bigger issue is that you are using a single property, workItem to hold a reference to your DispatchWorkItem.
In doLongWork you call workItem?.cancel() and then store a new DispatchWorkItem in the workItem property, but DispatchWorkItems are not cancelled pre-emptively.  Your code needs to periodically check the state of isCancelled.  When it references workItem it will be seeing the new DispatchWorkItem, not the item that represents 'itself'.
The solution is to capture the workItem property in a local variable inside the longWork function.  Then, no matter what happens to the workItem property, the code can see whether it has been cancelled.
class WorkManager {
    
    private var workItem: DispatchWorkItem?
    private var queue1 = DispatchQueue(label: "serialQueue")

    
    func doLongWork() {
        
        self.workItem?.cancel()
        let newWorkItem = DispatchWorkItem {
            longWork()
        }
        self.workItem = newWorkItem
        queue1.async(execute: newWorkItem)
        
        
        func longWork() {
            
            guard let workItem else {
                print("workItem is nil")
                return
            }
         
            var cancelled: Bool {
                return workItem.isCancelled
            }
            
            
            print("Starting work")
            
            recursiveFunction()
            
            func recursiveFunction(depth: Int = 0) {
                if depth > 5 {
                    print("Depth reached")
                    return
                }
                if cancelled {
                    print("cancelled")
                    return
                }
                print("Sleeping")
                Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)
                print("Wake up")
                recursiveFunction(depth: depth + 1)
            }
        }
    }
}

Note that I am using Thread.sleep() to simulate a CPU intensive task. sleeping threads is not something you should do in real code.

that worked perfectly! thanks! Just one question about thread safety before I mark it answered. I need to pass in to longWork() some data as an array of class objects that is a property of SomeClass (WorkManager in your sample code). The longWork() function doesn't modify the array, but the property could be modified while the longWork() function is running. If I pass in the array as a function parameter, will it remain constant the entire time, or will it refer to the class property and start using the new values if the data is changed?

(To be clear, I want the function to continue working on the original data array, not use any new or changed objects).

Probably you should consider adopting Swift async/await concurrency - Even if you stick with the DispatchQueue for managing the work you can use an actor to hold your array

I'm sticking with the GCD for now, I think the other concurrency methods will take much more time/effort to research and this solution is working well. Also I was able to devise a test that proved the longWork() function parameter of the passed in data array as an argument remained constant even when the original property was modified while the function was running. So it appears it is thread safe and will resolve all the issues I was experiencing. Thanks again!

If adopting legacy patterns, I might advise OperationQueue, which handles cancellation more elegantly than GCD. Or you could use Swift concurrency. I outline both below.

Legacy Operation queue

Create Operation subclass to wrap the work being performed. And have it periodically check to see if the operation has been canceled:
class CalculationOperation: Operation, @unchecked Sendable {
    typealias CompletionHandler = @MainActor (Result<Double, Error>) -> Void

    let completionHander: CompletionHandler

    init(completionHander: @escaping CompletionHandler) {
        self.completionHander = completionHander
        super.init()
    }

    override func main() {
        do {
            let result = try calculatePi(iterations: 1_000_000_000)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.completionHander(.success(result))
            }
        } catch {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.completionHander(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    }

    private func calculatePi(iterations: Int) throws -> Double {
        var result = 0.0
        var sign = 1.0
        for i in 0 ..< iterations {
            if i.isMultiple(of: 1_000) {
                if isCancelled {
                    throw CancellationError()
                }
            }
            result += sign / Double(i * 2 + 1)
            sign *= -1
        }
        return result * 4
    }
}


Then the process of adding items to that queue, canceling the prior one, is quite simple:
class WorkManager {
    let queue: OperationQueue = {
        let queue = OperationQueue()
        queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
        queue.name = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier! + ".SomeClass"
        return queue
    }()

    func longWork() {
        queue.cancelAllOperations()
        let operation = CalculationOperation { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let result): print(result)
            case .failure(let error):  print(error)
            }
        }
        queue.addOperation(operation)
    }
}

So, I profiled that, tapped the button quickly a few times, tapped slowly a few more times, and tapped again quickly a few more times, and you can see that it successfully stops prior calculations where needed (indicated by the ⓢ signposts).




Simple structured concurrency
The approach with Swift structured concurrency would be an actor. The trick here is that we have a contract with Swift concurrency to never impede forward progress on the cooperative thread pool, so you have to periodically await Task.yield:
actor WorkManager {
    private var task: Task<Double, Error>?

    func longWork() async throws -> Double {
        task?.cancel()             // cancel prior task
        _ = try? await task?.value // await it to respond to the cancelation

        // create new task and save reference to it

        let task = Task {
            try await calculatePi(iterations: 1_000_000_000)
        }
        self.task = task

        // await its result

        return try await withTaskCancellationHandler {
            try await task.value
        } onCancel: {
            task.cancel()
        }
    }

    private func calculatePi(iterations: Int) async throws -> Double {
        var result = 0.0
        var sign = 1.0
        for i in 0 ..< iterations {
            if i.isMultiple(of: 1_000_000) {
                await Task.yield()
                try Task.checkCancellation()
            }
            result += sign / Double(i * 2 + 1)
            sign *= -1
        }
        return result * 4
    }
}

That yields similar results (though the Task.yield has a material impact on performance):


Structured concurrency out of the cooperative thread pool
The alternative to periodically yielding to the Swift cooperative thread pool is to keep the calculation out of that pool altogether by giving it its own serial executor.

So we might have one object manage the cancelation and creation of tasks:
actor WorkManager {
    private var task: Task<Double, Error>?
    private let calculator = Calculator()

    func longWork() async throws -> Double {
        task?.cancel()

        let task = Task {
            try await calculator.calculatePi(iterations: 4_000_000_000)
        }
        self.task = task

        return try await withTaskCancellationHandler {
            try await task.value
        } onCancel: {
            task.cancel()
        }
    }
}


And then we would have another for doing the work (out of the cooperative thread pool):
actor Calculator {
    private let queue = DispatchSerialQueue(label: "SomeActor")

    nonisolated var unownedExecutor: UnownedSerialExecutor {
        queue.asUnownedSerialExecutor()
    }

    func calculatePi(iterations: Int) throws -> Double {
        var result = 0.0
        var sign = 1.0
        for i in 0 ..< iterations {
            if i.isMultiple(of: 10_000) {
                try Task.checkCancellation()
            }
            result += sign / Double(i * 2 + 1)
            sign *= -1
        }
        return result * 4
    }
}




Thank you so much for your input on my issue. That's a lot of new coding I've not seen before, so I will definitely be researching into it along with your solutions. However, I am marking the GCD solution by Paulw11  as the answer since I'll be using that one for the time being.

Yeah, doing slow synchronous calculations in Swift concurrency can be a little complicated. Using OperationQueue is the simple legacy approach.
